# SQL for balance due without grouping all select

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I've provided a summary of my tables and I've gotten a good start on the SQL, but I'm stuck on figuring out how to limit how many items are returned. I should be able to choose one or more terms, and get back the balance due from just those terms.

A student should have 1 record, they can have several reservations over several terms, but payment is not specific to the reservation but rather to the student. That is the part that is throwing me off.

Table structure, date and the start of my SQL follow. Can someone help me with it please? This result should not be showing the $500 payment from term 3 for Sue Smith.

I'm using PostgreSQL, but I think this is a pretty basic question that doesn't require anything specific to Postgres.

### Current result set:

```
Student ID  Last        First   Total Fees  Reservation Count   Amount Paid Amount Due
123456      Jones       Amy     50          1                   50          0
412365      Smith       Sue     100         3                   545         -445
741258      Anderson    Jon     50          1                   0.00        50.00
963258      Holmes      Fred    100         2                   30          70
```

### The schema:

```
SET search_path TO temp, public;
CREATE TABLE term
(term_id                SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
term_title              VARCHAR(100));

CREATE TABLE student
(student_id                 SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
student_sis_id              VARCHAR(15),   
student_first_name              VARCHAR(30),
student_last_name               VARCHAR(100)); 

CREATE TABLE reservation
(reservation_id                      SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
student_id                          INTEGER REFERENCES student ON UPDATE CASCADE,
term_id                             INTEGER REFERENCES term ON UPDATE CASCADE,   
reservation_fee_amount              NUMERIC DEFAULT 0.00);

CREATE TABLE payment
(payment_id                  SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
student_id                  INTEGER REFERENCES student ON UPDATE CASCADE,
term_id                     INTEGER REFERENCES term ON UPDATE CASCADE,
payment_cash_amount         NUMERIC,
payment_credit_card_amount  NUMERIC,
payment_check_amount        NUMERIC);

INSERT INTO term VALUES (DEFAULT, 'SESSION 1');
INSERT INTO term VALUES (DEFAULT, 'SESSION 2');
INSERT INTO term VALUES (DEFAULT, 'SESSION 3'); 

INSERT INTO student VALUES (DEFAULT, 412365, 'Sue', 'Smith');
INSERT INTO student VALUES (DEFAULT, 123456, 'Amy', 'Jones');
INSERT INTO student VALUES (DEFAULT, 741258, 'Jon', 'Anderson');
INSERT INTO student VALUES (DEFAULT, 963258, 'Fred', 'Holmes');

INSERT INTO reservation VALUES (DEFAULT, 1, 1, 50);
INSERT INTO reservation VALUES (DEFAULT, 1, 2, 50);
INSERT INTO reservation VALUES (DEFAULT, 2, 1, 50);
INSERT INTO reservation VALUES (DEFAULT, 3, 2, 50);
INSERT INTO reservation VALUES (DEFAULT, 4, 1, 50);
INSERT INTO reservation VALUES (DEFAULT, 4, 2, 50);
INSERT INTO reservation VALUES (DEFAULT, 1, 3, 50);

INSERT INTO payment VALUES (DEFAULT, 1, 1, 25, 0, 0);
INSERT INTO payment VALUES (DEFAULT, 1, 1, 0, 20, 0);
INSERT INTO payment VALUES (DEFAULT, 2, 1, 25, 25, 0);
INSERT INTO payment VALUES (DEFAULT, 4, 1, 10, 10, 10);
INSERT INTO payment VALUES (DEFAULT, 1, 3, 500, 0, 0);
```

### The query:

```
SELECT      
    student.student_sis_id AS "Student ID",        
    student.student_last_name AS Last,
    student.student_first_name AS First,
    SUM(reservation.reservation_fee_amount) AS "Total Fees",
    (
        SELECT COUNT(reservation.reservation_id)
        FROM reservation
        WHERE student.student_id = reservation.student_id
    ) AS "Reservation Count",
    (
        SELECT 
            COALESCE(SUM(
                payment.payment_check_amount
                + payment.payment_cash_amount
                + payment.payment_credit_card_amount
            ), 0.00)  
        FROM payment 
        WHERE payment.student_id = student.student_id
    ) AS "Amount Paid",
    SUM(reservation.reservation_fee_amount) - (
        SELECT 
            COALESCE(SUM(
                payment.payment_check_amount
                + payment.payment_cash_amount
                + payment.payment_credit_card_amount
            ), 0.00)  
        FROM payment WHERE payment.student_id = student.student_id
    ) AS "Amount Due" 
FROM 
    student
    INNER JOIN reservation ON student.student_id = reservation.student_id  
WHERE reservation.term_id IN (1,2)
GROUP BY
    student.student_id, 
    student.student_sis_id,        
    student.student_last_name,
    student.student_first_name
ORDER BY 
    student.student_sis_id
;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my updated version of the query:

```
SELECT      
    s.student_sis_id AS "Student ID",        
    s.student_last_name AS Last,
    s.student_first_name AS First,
    SUM(r.reservation_fee_amount) AS "Total Fees",
    COUNT(r.reservation_id) AS "Reservation Count",
    COALESCE(
        SUM(
            p.payment_check_amount
            + p.payment_cash_amount
            + p.payment_credit_card_amount
        ), 0.00
    ) AS "Amount Paid",
    SUM(r.reservation_fee_amount) - (
        COALESCE(
            SUM(
                p.payment_check_amount
                + p.payment_cash_amount
                + p.payment_credit_card_amount
            ), 0.00
        )  
    ) AS "Amount Due" 
FROM 
    student s
    INNER JOIN reservation r ON s.student_id = r.student_id  
    LEFT JOIN payment p ON p.student_id = r.student_id AND p.term_id = r.term_id
WHERE r.term_id IN (1,2)
GROUP BY
    s.student_id, 
    s.student_sis_id,        
    s.student_last_name,
    s.student_first_name
ORDER BY 
    s.student_sis_id
;
```

Things to watch:

- I included `payments` in the main (outer) query in order to avoid subqueries
- the join type is `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN`, so the lack of any `payment` rows will not prevent other data from appearing in the result set
- the join condition includes `term_id` (basically this was the point where you were lost, I think)
- and finally I used short table aliases for improving readability.

I hope this is what you are after.

Comment: That is exactly it, thank you. And thanks for the headers on my question, didn't think of that. I try to ask a quality question - it seems to attract quality answers, like yours.

Comment: @user973828 - your question was of good quality indeed.  A small addition: you can avoid pasting so much code (say the `INSERT`s) by using [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/).

Comment: Hi, additional question.. If I add the following to the From clause:  FROM 
     student s     
     INNER JOIN reservation r ON s.student_id = r.student_id
     LEFT JOIN payment p ON p.student_id = r.student_id AND p.term_id = r.term_id      
  WHERE r.reservation_completed
  AND r.reservation_deleted_date Is NULL
  AND NOT r.reservation_waitlisted
  AND r.term_id IN ($list)                              I get a fee for a reservation_completed that is false. I don't understand why??

Comment: The fee is being doubled because the student made 2 payments towards one reservation. Do I need to have a sub-query of payments to handle that situation?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution to the 2 payment entry problem (that I didn't recognize in my original question). Here is the answer:

```
set search_path to temp, public;
SELECT      
s.student_sis_id AS "Student ID",        
s.student_last_name AS "Last Name",
s.student_first_name AS "First Name",
SUM(r.reservation_fee_amount) AS "Total Fees",
COALESCE(p.paid, 0.00) AS "Amount Paid",
COALESCE(SUM(r.reservation_fee_amount) - p.paid, 0.00) AS "Amount Due"    
FROM 
    student s       
    INNER JOIN reservation r ON s.student_id = r.student_id
    left outer join 
    (
      select student_id, term_id,
        SUM(
            p.payment_check_amount
            + p.payment_cash_amount
            + p.payment_credit_card_amount
        ) AS "paid" 
      from payment p
      group by student_id, term_id
    ) as p 
    ON p.student_id = r.student_id AND p.term_id = r.term_id
        WHERE r.reservation_completed  AND  r.term_id IN (1,2)                      
GROUP BY
    s.student_sis_id,        
    s.student_last_name,
    s.student_first_name,
    p.paid
ORDER BY 
    s.student_sis_id
```

Thank you dezso and davek